# Fatal error: Class NAME not found in (....PATH)?

Tags: php

What may be the problem if i get the following error.

Fatal error: Class NAME not found in (....PATH) ?

I have done most of the possibilities... But i can't resolve the problem.

any help will be thankful

thanks n advance

Fero

Comment: exact duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678989/fatal-error-class-name-not-found-in-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have included the abstract class, it can implement, extens etc if the code isnt included.