# Fatal error: Class NAME not found in (....PATH)?

Tags: php, oop, class, abstraction

What may be the problem if i get the following error.

while i am extending a class i got this error

example:

> class ModuleUser extends
>   AbstractModule

Fatal error: Class AbstractModule not found in (....PATH) ?

I have done most of the possibilities... But i can't resolve the problem.

any help will be thankful

thanks n advance

Fero

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678981/fatal-error-class-name-not-found-in-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to your definition of ModuleUser, import the file that contains the definition for AbstractModule.

```
require_once 'path/to/abstract_module.php';
```

If both classes are in the same file, then make sure you define the class ModuleUser **after** you define AbstractModule.